# How to specify namespace when querying nodes with XPath?

Tags: winapi, com, msxml, msxml6

## Short Version

- You do it in .NET with:

  ```
  XmlNode.SelectNodes(query, selectionNamespaces);
  ```
- Can you do it in javascript?

  - https://jsfiddle.net/9ctoxbh0/
- Can you do it in msxml?

**Attempt A**:

```
IXMLDOMNode.selectNodes(query); //no namespaces option
```

**Attempt B**:

```
IXMLDOMNode.ownerDocument.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", selectionNamespaces);
IXMLDOMNode.selectNodes(query); //doesn't work
```

**Attempt C**:

```
IXMLDOMDocument3 doc;
doc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", selectionNamespaces);
IXMLDOMNodeList list = doc.selectNodes(...)[0].selectNodes(query); //doesn't work
```

## Long Version

Given an [**IXMLDOMNode**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms761386(v%3Dvs.85)) containing a fragment of xml:

```
<row>
    <cell>a</cell>
    <cell>b</cell>
    <cell>c</cell>
</row>
```

We can use the [**IXMLDOMNode.selectNodes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754523%28v%3Dvs.85%29) method to select child elements:

```
IXMLDOMNode row = //...xml above

IXMLDOMNodeList cells = row.selectNodes("/row/cell");
```

and that will return an **IXMLDOMNodeList**:

- `<cell>a</cell>`
- `<cell>b</cell>`
- `<cell>c</cell>`

And that's fine.

### But namespaces break it

If the XML fragment originated from a document with a namespace, e.g.:

```
<row xmlns:ss="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
    <cell>a</cell>
    <cell>b</cell>
    <cell>c</cell>
</row>
```

The same XPath query will nothing, because the elements `row` and `cell` do not exist; they are in another namespace.

### Querying documents with default namespace

If you had a full **IXMLDOMDocument**, you would use the **setProperty** method to set a *selection namespace*:

a
       b
       c

You would query the default namespace by **giving** it a name, e.g.:

- **Before**: `xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"`
- **After**: `xmlns:peanut="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"`

and then you *can* query it:

```
IXMLDOMDocument3 doc = //...document xml above
doc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:peanut="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main");

IXMLDOMNodeList cells = doc.selectNodes("/peanut:row/peanut:cell");
```

and you get your cells:

- `<cell>a</cell>`
- `<cell>b</cell>`
- `<cell>c</cell>`

### But that doesn't work for a node

An IXMLDOMNode has a [method to perform XPath queries:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754523(v%3Dvs.85))

> **selectNodes Method**
>
> Applies the specified pattern-matching operation to this node's context and returns the list of matching nodes as `IXMLDOMNodeList`.
>
> ```
> HRESULT selectNodes(  
>       BSTR expression,  
>       IXMLDOMNodeList **resultList);
> ```
>
> **Remarks**
>
> For more information about using the `selectNodes` method with namespaces, see the [setProperty Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760290%28v%3Dvs.85%29) topic.

But there's no way to specify Selection Namespaces when issuing an XPath query against a DOM Node.

How can I specify a namespace when querying nodes with XPath?

## .NET Solution

.NET's **XmlNode** provides a **SelectNodes** method that provides accepts a `XmlNamespaceManager` parameter:

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("peanut", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main");
cells = row.SelectNodes("/peanut:row/peanut:cell", ns);
```

But i'm not in C# (nor am i in Javascript). What's the native msxml6 equivalent?

**Edit**: Me not so much with the Javascript *([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ctoxbh0/))*

## Complete Minimal Example

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, msxml, ActiveX;

procedure Main;
var
    s: string;
    doc: DOMDocument60;
    rows: IXMLDOMNodeList;
    row: IXMLDOMElement;
    cells: IXMLDOMNodeList;
begin
    s :=
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>'+#13#10+
            '<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">'+#13#10+
            '<row>'+#13#10+
            '    <cell>a</cell>'+#13#10+
            '    <cell>b</cell>'+#13#10+
            '    <cell>c</cell>'+#13#10+
            '</row>'+#13#10+
            '</worksheet>';

    doc := CoDOMDocument60.Create;
    doc.loadXML(s);
    if doc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Parse error: %s', [doc.parseError.reason]);

    doc.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:ss="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"');

    //Query for all the rows
    rows := doc.selectNodes('/ss:worksheet/ss:row');
    if rows.length = 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('Could not find any rows');

    //Do stuff with the first row
    row := rows[0] as IXMLDOMElement;

    //Get the cells in the row
    (row.ownerDocument as IXMLDOMDocument3).setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:ss="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"');
    cells := row.selectNodes('/ss:row/ss:cell');
    if cells.length <> 3 then
        raise Exception.CreateFmt('Did not find 3 cells in the first row (%d)', [cells.length]);
end;

begin
  try
        CoInitialize(nil);
        Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: `node.ownerDocument.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces"....`

Comment: @Ben It was a fine idea. Unfortunately it simply doesn't work - it simply doesn't return any nodes.

Comment: Have you got a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Ben I'm not using javascript (i'm using native Win32 COM msxml). Have you got a jsFiddle?

Comment: I haven't, but it should be possible to reproduce the issue with JScript/Windows script host?

Answer (score 1):

This is answered on MSDN:

[How To Specify Namespace when Querying the DOM with XPath](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/294797/how-to-specify-namespace-when-querying-the-dom-with-xpath)

**Update:**

Note, however, that in your second example XML, the `<row>` and `<cell>` elements are NOT in the namespace being queried by the XPath when adding `xmlns:peanut` to the `SelectionNamespaces` property. That is why the `<cell>` elements are not being found.

To put them into the namespace properly, you would have to either:

- change the namespace declaration to use `xmlns=` instead of `xmlns:ss=`:

  ```xml
  <row xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
      <cell>a</cell>
      <cell>b</cell>
      <cell>c</cell>
  </row>
  ```
- use `<ss:row>` and `<ss:cell>` instead of `<row>` and `<cell>`:

  ```xml
  <ss:row xmlns:ss="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
      <ss:cell>a</cell>
      <ss:cell>b</cell>
      <ss:cell>c</cell>
  </ss:row>
  ```

The `SelectionNamespaces` property does not magically put elements into a namespace for you, it only specifies which namespaces are available for the XPath query to use. The XML itself has to put elements into the proper namespaces as needed.

**Update:**

In your new example, `cells := row.selectNodes('/ss:row/ss:cell');` does not work because the XPath query is using an **absolute** path, where the leading `/` starts at the document root, and there are no `<row>` elements at the top of the XML document, only a `<worksheet>` element.  That is why `rows := doc.selectNodes('/ss:worksheet/ss:row');` works.

If you want to perform an XPath query that begins at the node being queried, don't use an **absolute** path, use a **relative** path instead:

```
cells := row.selectNodes('ss:row/ss:cell');
```

Or simply:

```
cells := row.selectNodes('ss:cell');
```

Comment: As far as i can tell that code calls `Document.setProperty`. (i.e. it is querying a *document* and not a *node*)

Comment: Yes, because [`SelectionNamespaces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms756048(v%3Dvs.85)) is a property of the DOM document as a whole, not of individual nodes. When you run an XPath query, regardless of which node you run the query on, it will use the document's current `SelectedNamespaces` property to resolve namespaces in the query.

Comment: Except setting the document's `SelectionNamespaces` does not resolve the namespaces in the query; it simply does not work. Ben already suggested that above.

Comment: @IanBoyd It does work, I've used it before. Did you take note of the extra info I added to my answer?

Comment: You say that adding a `SelectionNamespaces` property does not magically put elements into a namesapce for me. Why is it that when when i add a `SelectionNamespace` it magically puts the elements into the proper namespace for me? Added complete minimal example to question.

Comment: @IanBoyd "*Why is it that when when i add a SelectionNamespace it magically puts the elements into the proper namespace for me?*" - it doesn't, it only defines the prefixes that can be used within the query. You have now shown a completely different XML example that has the `<row>` and `<cell>` elements ALREADY in the namespace via the `xmlns` declaration on the parent `<worksheet>` element. That is not what you originally asked about.

Comment: And if you look at the *intermediate* xml, it has a namespace on it - already - for me - without me specifying anything. (i assume you know that when selecting nodes the namespace of the parent, the children automatically get the same namespace on the resulting xml fragment)

Comment: @IanBoyd in your new example, the XPath query of `row` is using an absolute path when it should be using a relative path instead. That is why it is not finding any results. I have updated my answer.